# Why would the JIT run in the middle of program when no new code is being run?

Tags: c#-4.0, .net-4.0, clr, jit

I'm running some performance tests on some webservers that host .Net 4.0 code. I've noticed that the % in JIT counter will spike seemingly randomly in the process of the tests.

These test are fairly simple, and they all run through the same code. There are no other people accessing these servers so it's only running the code I put on there, and there is only one code path I'm testing.

In a one hour test I'll see the % in JIT counter spike up to 50%-100% about 30-40 times. It's only for a short period of time, and the rest of the time it's at 0%, but I can't think of any reason for this to be occurring. I did all the normal checking the event logs and looking for errors in different log files, but everything appears to be operating normal, so it wasn't even like it had to catch and exception and run different code.

I realize this is a vague question and I'm sure there are 1,000s of different reasons that the JIT compiler could be running, but I was hoping someone might know of some common reasons why it would be occurring in code that is already "warmed up", when there aren't any new code paths being run. Or if this is just normal everyday behavior.